# Sort List<T> collection by method result.

Tags: c#, sorting, lambda

I have the next class and collection of this classes. How can I sort this collection by Perimeter() by asc?

```
    public class Circle
    {
        private double _r;

        public Double Radius
        {
            get { return _r; }
            set { _r = value; }
        }

        public double Perimeter ()
        {
            return 2*Math.PI*Radius;
        }
    }
...
var lst = new List<Circle>();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lst = lst.OrderBy(x => x.Perimeter()).ToList()` should to the trick. There is also an `OrderByDesc` method available.

Of course you can also use the LINQ query syntax as Rob4md propses, however **keep in mind that all LINQ queries return an IEnumerable and are executed lazily.**
You should use an eager operation like `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to execute them as soon as it makes sense because you may end up executing the enumeration multiple times.

You may take a look at the [101 LINQ Samples page at the MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b). There are many samples on how to use LINQ, [OrderBy](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Ordering-Operators-050af19e) is covered, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a linq statement to execute this.  Try this Console program using your circle class:

```
        var circles = new List<Circle>();
        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Circle c = new Circle();
            c.Radius = i;
            circles.Add(c);
        }

        var orderList = from c in circles
                        orderby c.Perimeter() ascending
                        select c;

        foreach (var circle in orderList)
            Console.WriteLine(circle.Perimeter());
```

Comment: you could even use LINQ to generate your list: `var cirlces = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x => new Circle{ Radius = 10-x });`

Answer (score 0):

List has a Sort method, which takes a comparer object as input.

First, you define the comparer:

```
public class PerimeterComparer: IComparer<Circle>
{
  public int Compare(Circle x, Circle y)
  {
    if(x.Perimeter() > y.Perimeter()) { return -1; }
    if(x.Perimeter() < y.Perimeter()) { return 1; }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Then call sort method:

```
lst.Sort(new PerimeterComparer());
```